# Sony NP-FH40 not charging well

Tags: sony, battery

I have Sony Handycam DCR DVD610 which works perfectly fine with the power adapter on. But if I take it out and put it on battery power, it turns off for 20 seconds and will say battery exhausted. Even though the battery was fully charged. I even tested one Chinese charger and it wont work. The weird thing is, when i plug in the charger, the battery jumped from 1% to 100% (1 min to 107 min.) By the way, we did not charge or use the camera for a WHOLE 6 YEARS. It was just laying there, picking up dust.

So please, can someone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is probably very simple: The battery is dead.

Lithium-Ion batteries lose some charge when they are stored. The self-discharge rate typically stated by manufacturers is around 1.5–2% per month.

If that period is extended, they can become deeply discharged, which may damage the cells in the battery.

As a result, they lose a lot of capacity or can even become so damaged that they hold no real charge anymore.

Please also note that batteries age and this effect adds to a decrease in capacity as well.

The good news is, they have become cheaper and a new one will set you back around $15.